# for loop multiple variable, second variable not updating

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to write two loops in one for loop so I looked up the syntax for multiple variables in the for loop

the problem is the second variable `l` isn't updating  I don't know why

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float vsum=0, lsum=0;
    double nsum=0, msum=0;
    float v=1, l=100000000;
    for (v, l ; v<= 100000000, l >= 1 ;  v++, l--)
    {
        vsum= vsum + 1/v;
        nsum= nsum + 1/v;
        lsum= lsum + 1/l;
        msum= msum+ 1/l; 
    }
    cout << " The float sum of all numbers 1 through 1/100000000 is " << vsum << endl;
    cout << " The double sum of all numbers 1 through 1/100000000 is " << nsum << endl;
    cout << "The float sum of all numbers 1/100000000 through 1/1 is " << lsum << endl;
    cout << "The double sum of all numbers 1/100000000 through 1/1 is " << msum << endl;
    cin >> vsum; 
}
```

Comment: Please use indentation - makes the code readable

Comment: Why do you think the second variable isn't updating? It seems to be updating perfectly fine for me.

Comment: This comma expression does not do what you think it should be doing: `v<= 100000000, l >= 1`. It checks only the second variable (technically, it checks the first one as well, but it discards the results). The end result is the same as `l >= 1` by itself.

Comment: the sum using the second variable gives me 0 so i debugged it and going step by step i noticed l wasn't updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your question is that after

```
float f = 100000000;
```

why does `--f;` leave `f` unchanged?

The answer is due to the granularity of `float`.  The `float` does not have enough accuracy to store every possible integer. Clearly a 32-bit float cannot store as many integer values as a 32-bit int, for example.

The further away from `0` you get, the larger the gap gets between successive possible values of a `float`. On your system `100000000 - 1` is still larger than the next possible value of float below `100000000`.

The rules of C++ are that when the result of the calculation is not representable exactly by a float, then it's implementation-defined whether the next-lowest value or the next-highest value is used. (So your compiler should actually document what happens here). In this case your system is using the next-highest value.

To get your intended results, make `v` and `l` be integral types, and do a float conversion in the actual calculation, e.g.

```
vsum += 1.f/v;
nsum += 1.0/v;
```

Answer (score 1):

As dasblinkenlight mentions, you are only checking the second condition, but the second variable is updating just fine. Here is an abridged example that proves this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{

    float vsum=0, lsum=0;
    double nsum=0, msum=0;
    float v=1, l=10;
    for (v, l ; v<= 10, l >= 1 ;  v++, l--)
    {
        cout << v << " " << l << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 10
2 9
3 8
4 7
5 6
6 5
7 4
8 3
9 2
10 1
```